# Photos by hashtag are searched only in my account

Tags: api, oauth, instagram-api

The problem is related with tokens. This is how I receive tokens:

Firstly, I receive COD:

```
<p>https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&response_type=code&scope=public_content</p>
```

Then token:
"../oauth/access_token/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&code=[CODE]";

To receive photos by hashtag I sent such a request:

```
"../v1/tags/[TAGS]/media/recent?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&count=[IMG_COUNT];
```

If I use the token that I receive from Instagram, photos by hashtag are searched only in my account.
But if I use token that I found for tests in the internet, I receive all photos with necessary hashtag, not only those I have in my account.

How can I get the right ACCESS_TOKEN to receive photos with my hashtag from all accounts?

I made a widget for website. In 'Permissions Review' it is said that sending in Review if I 'widget for website' is not necessary. So, should I send widget to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are in sandbox mode, so the data returned by API will only show media from sandbox authorized users, which is you, u can add more users to sandbox.

Read here for sandbox mode limitations:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Once your app is reviewed and live, all data will be available in API